# QGIS Slope not working properly

Tags: qgis, dem, error, slope

I'm new in QGIS and I have been having an issue with it.

The thing is that I'm trying to get the slope and relief of a zone. I have the contour lines, from that I created the DEM with 'Rasterize' > 'Fill no data' and it looks pretty good to me. But when I apply 'Slope' and 'Relief' it creates a weird interaction:

(Slope between 0 and 81,9)
[image: Slope between 0 and 81,9]

(Zoomed in)
[image: Zoomed in]

(Relief)
[image: Relief]

Someone knows what is going on?

Comment: Doesnt look too wrong to me. Most likely the error happend during rasterize or rather fill no data. Can you confirm your inputdata aka "Filled" is correct?

Comment: When I used the 'Rasterize' tool, I followed this steeps:
- Input: Contour lines; Field to use to burn: height above sea level; Output raster units: pixels; Width: 1000; Height: 1000; Output: (previous known)...
And for fill-nodata the distance for interpolate was 1000